# Printing the value of items in array

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have a variable set as:

```
X="AA BB CC DD EE"
Y="AA DD EE"
```

Then each value have its own values assigned as below:

```
AA="after"
BB="before"
CC="care"
DD="driver"
EE="escape"
```

Then I need to loop through these variables and need to get its corresponding values to be printed.

```
for myloop in `echo $Y`
do
    # Now I need to print each variable  
    echo ${$myloop} # if its value is number then I can use ((myloop)) to print it
done
```

The output should be:

```
after
driver
escape
```

How can I achieve this using shell script? I am not using any array.

Comment: You are looking for variable indirection. Given `name=a` and `a=text` `${!name}` returns the value in `$a`.

Comment: That is bash-specific, though. A POSIX way is to `eval var="\$$myloop"` and then use `$var`.